# Java TFTP implementation with std libs - how to ack packets?

Tags: java, sockets, network-programming

I have tried to implement a TFTP client / server. As per RFC 1350 i got everything right only thing missing now is to confirm each packet that is received by whoever is receiving it be it client or server.

1. Server sends a datagram packet
2. Client receives the datagram packet and sends back ACK ("confirm") msg in a packet
3. Server sends next packet

If Client does not send ACK in say 20s then Server transferes the same packet again until it receives ACK from the Client.

Here is my method for sending and receiving packets. They both work i just need to add the above but i have no absolutely no clue how to implement that.

Server:

```
private void receiveData() throws Exception
{
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    SimpleDateFormat prefix = new SimpleDateFormat(date_format);
    String date = prefix.format(cal.getTime()).toString();

    DatagramPacket receiveData = new DatagramPacket(incomingData, incomingData.length);
    OutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(new File(date+data));

    while(true)
    {
        clientSocket.receive(receiveData);
        if(receiveData.getLength() == 512)
        {
            fos.write(receiveData.getData());
        } else {
            fos.write(receiveData.getData(), receiveData.getOffset(), receiveData.getLength());
            break;
        }
    }
    fos.close();
    clientSocket.close();
}
```

Client:

```
    private void sendData() throws Exception {
    DatagramPacket data = new DatagramPacket(outgoingData,
            outgoingData.length, clientAddress, clientPort);
    InputStream fis = new FileInputStream(responseData);

    int a;
    while ((a = fis.read(outgoingData, 0, 512)) != -1) {
        data.setLength(a);
        serverSocket.send(data);
        Thread.sleep(5);
    }
    fis.close();
```

I am just learning about network programing so would be thankful for any suggestions or code examples.

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved:

1. sendData() sends a packet
2. receiveData() gets the packet and sends it back
3. sendData() checks if the packet is the same as the one that was sent
4. sendData() if it is it sends next one or transfers the same one again

Answer (score 0):

1. Build the required data into a `DatagramPacket`. As this is a reply, it is best to reuse the incoming `DatagramPacket`. That way it already has the target address in it.
2. Send it.

Comment: No. The APIs you need are `DatagramPacket.setData()` and `DatagramSocket.send()`.

Comment: I been at this for 2 days i got nothing. Thanks for help anyways. I tried to implement what you said i rewrote my method but didnt get far: http://www.copypastecode.com/187840/

Comment: I don't see where in that code you have taken any of my advice, so there is no point in even showing it to me.